# How to plot a graph for infinite series converging to a known value w.r.t with number of terms using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

Let's say I have a series which converges to a known value, with each increasing number of terms to approximate it. For example:

```
\pi = 4 ( 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ... )
```

How can I make a plot which shows the approximation works for larger number of terms? If possible then, a logarithmic scale of number of terms in x-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a loop.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,5) node[below left] {$p(n)$} 
  |- (10,0) node[below left] {$n$} ;
 \draw foreach \X in {1,...,18} {(\X/2,0.1) -- (\X/2,-0.1)};
 \draw[dashed] (0,pi) node[left]{$\pi$} -- (10,pi);
 \edef\x{1}
 \edef\mysum{1}
 \edef\lstc{(0.5*\x,4*\mysum)}
 \loop
  \edef\mysum{\fpeval{\mysum+(-1)^\x/(2*\x+1)}}
  \edef\x{\the\numexpr\x+1}
  \edef\lstc{\lstc (0.5*\x,4*\mysum)}
 \ifnum\x<19\repeat
 \draw plot[only marks,mark=*] coordinates {\lstc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]